# How to replace the date with "sed" by the words "today" or "tomorrow"

Tags: date, sed

my goal is to retrieve tidal times from www.worldtides.info in a specific way.

I got an API key on the site and can successfully retrieve the infos by issuing:

```
curl -s "http://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=my_latitude&lon=my_longitude&length=86400&key=my_api_key"| jq -r ".extremes[] | .date + .type"
```

I've installed jq on my raspberry to parse "date" and "type" from the json result.

The result in the terminal is:

```
2016-04-03T16:47+0000Low
2016-04-03T23:01+0000High
2016-04-04T05:18+0000Low
2016-04-04T11:29+0000High
```

To get a cleaner result, i use sed:

```
curl -s "http://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=my_latitude&lon=my_longitude&length=86400&key=my_api_key"| jq -r ".extremes[] | .date + .type" | sed 's/+0000/ /g' | sed 's/T/ /g'|
```

The result is:

```
2016-04-03 16:47 Low
2016-04-03 23:01 High
2016-04-04 05:18 Low
2016-04-04 11:29 High
```

I don't know how to replace the date by the word "today" if it's the date of today (2016-04-03 when i'm writing right now) and how to replace the date by the word "tomorrow" if it's the date of tomorrow.

I've tried:

```
curl -s "http://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=my_latitude&lon=my_longitude&length=86400&key=my_api_key"| jq -r ".extremes[] | .date + .type" | sed 's/date +"%Y-%m-%d"/Today/g' | sed 's/+0000/ /g' | sed 's/T/ /g'|
```

But no luck, no change. Can you help me ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the substitution this way:

```
today=`date  +%Y-%m-%d`
tomorrow=`date --date="tomorrow" +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $today $tomorrow
sed "s/$today/today/g; s/$tomorrow/tomorrow/g;" your_last_result
```

where `your_last_result` is the file containing the data from your question below "The result is:"

Answer (score 2):

Some lean linux distribution do not have GNU `date` out-of-the-box but use POSIX `date` without a *tomorrow* function. So you might have to install it first if you want to use `sed` with `date`. Alternatively, if GNU `awk` is available, you can also do

```
awk '$1 ~ strftime("%Y-%m-%d") {$1 = "today"} $1 ~ strftime("%Y-%m-%d",systime()+24*3600) {$1 = "tomorrow"} {print}'
```